# cannot access contacts from MS graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I try to retrieve a list of all contacts that are added to our microsoft 365 admin, I login in the graph explorer with the account that has access to the admin center and grant permission to read contacts but still get this error:

> The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have valid M365 license assigned. You are getting this error because no Exchange Online mailbox is available to use for the azure ad user who do not have a valid M365 license. Please note that Exchange Online mailbox and outlook calendars will only be available/created for the users with a valid M365 license.

you can check the link, if you have valid subscription - https://outlook.office.com/mail
[image]

Comment: ok so the contacts added here cannot be reached via ms graph api?

Comment: yes , it can . you can check with the link i provided if you have correct subscription.

Comment: no this user is the user that created the non profit portal organization, but its there all contacts are added and is available for the other mailboxes in the organization. I'm kinda lost here on how to access those contacts or be able to add contacts that are available to all other accounts in the organisation

Comment: could you please provide us the complete error with request and timestamp .